# How can I have components from my library communicate with my server without exposing sensitive information to the client?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, firebase, npm, environment-variables

I am trying to build my first library, which is a react component library that handles some tasks for the client.
One of these tasks for example is authenticating users which I intend on doing with Firebase.
Another one would be saving certain user input to a Mongo server (all is intended to be stored in my server).

What I can't understand is - how can my components do all that in my client's app without me exposing all the secret information (e.g. firebase config file, or mongo atlas connection string with username and password)?

** Feel free to suggest an edit for the tags to something different I feel like none of them really fit but these are the closest I could come up with.